# Access filters within a convolutional layer - TensorFlow2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am using TF2.5 & Python3.8 where a conv layer is defined as:

```
Conv2D(
    filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3),
    activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotNormal(),
    strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same',
)
```

Using a batch of 60 CIFAR-10 dataset as input:

```
x.shape
# TensorShape([60, 32, 32, 3])
```

Output volume of this layer preserves the spatial width and height (32, 32) and has 64 filters/kernel maps applied to the 60 images as batch-

```
conv1(x).shape
# TensorShape([60, 32, 32, 64])

conv1.kernel.shape
# TensorShape([3, 3, 3, 64])
```

In this output, the first (3, 3) is the spatial width and height of the filters/kernels applied in this conv layer. The third 3 refers to the number of input channels provided to this layer and 64 refers to the number of filters applied.

How can I access the 64 filters applied in this conv layer?

Currently I am using the code:

```
filters = conv1.kernel[:, :, 0, :]

filters.shape
# TensorShape([3, 3, 64])
```

Is this correct? Also, how can I iterate over the 64 different filters of this conv layer?

Thanks

Comment: `model.layers[3].get_weights()`?

Comment: @NicolasGervais This won't work. First, ```model.layers[3].get_weights()``` returns a list where the first element returns (for example) (3, 3, 64, 128) and the second element returns (128,). So that will be ```model.layers[3].get_weights()[0]``` and ```model.layers[3].get_weights[1]```. And no, this doesn't return the filters which I am interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tf.split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) with `model.layers[...].get_weights()`

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2()

conv_layer = model.layers[1]

[weights] = conv_layer.get_weights()

list_of_filters = tf.split(weights, axis=-1, num_or_size_splits=weights.shape[-1])
```

This will return a list of 32 filters with shape `TensorShape([3, 3, 3, 1])`